# Android Circle following touch and drag on screen

Tags: java, android, touch, geometry

I have a simple app that draws a line as you move your finger around the screen.

I want to change it so instead of it drawing behind the finger, a circle follows directly below where you have touched. As you move your finger along the screen the circle should follow. It should not leave a path behind it.

The circle should appear where the finger is when the screen is touched and disappear when the finger is lifted.

MainActivity:

```
package com.example.dot2;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(new SingleTouchEventListener(this, null));
  }
}
```

SingleTouchEventListener:

```
package com.example.dot2;

import...

public class SingleTouchEventListener extends View {
 private Paint paint = new Paint();
 private Path path = new Path();
 private Paint mPaint;


public SingleTouchEventListener(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
super(context, attrs);

paint.setAntiAlias(true);
paint.setStrokeWidth(6f);
paint.setColor(Color.RED);
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);

}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
 canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
 float eventX = event.getX();
 float eventY = event.getY();

switch (event.getAction()) {
case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
  path.moveTo(eventX, eventY);
  return true;
case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
  path.lineTo(eventX, eventY);
  break;
case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
  // nothing to do
  break;
default:
  return false;
}

// Schedules a repaint.
invalidate();
return true;
}
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually found code which did most of what I needed and added the rest...

Here's the code:

```
public class drawingView extends View implements OnTouchListener{

static int x,y,r=255,g=255,b=255;
final static int radius=30;
Paint paint;   

public drawingView(Context context)
{
    super(context);
        paint=new Paint();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);      
    paint.setARGB(255, r, g, b);    

    setFocusable(true);

    this.setOnTouchListener(this);
}

public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    paint.setARGB(255, r, g, b);

    //drawing the circle
    canvas.drawCircle(x,y,radius,paint);

}

public boolean onTouch(View view,MotionEvent event)
{
    x=(int)event.getX()-(radius/2);      //logic to plot the circle in exact touch place
    y=(int)event.getY()-(radius/2);
      //System.out.println("X,Y:"+"x"+","+y);      
    randColor();  
    invalidate(); 


    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        paint.setARGB(12, r, g, b);
    }
    return true;

}



public void randColor()
{
    //r=(int)(Math.random()*255);
    //g=(int)(Math.random()*255);
    //b=(int)(Math.random()*255);
    r=1;
    g=2;
    b=3;
    //Toast.makeText(c, "r,g,b="+r+","+g+","+b,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

public void dissColor(){

    r=255;
    g=255;
    b=255;

}
}
```